# Wrong Node.js version on Next.js

Tags: node.js, next.js, path, nvm, volta

I am a relatively new to node.js and next.js and I just started a project on Next.js. As soon as I type

> npm run dev

I get the following error:

***You are using Node.js 18.12.1. For Next.js, Node.js version >= v18.17.0 is required.***

First thing I automatically did was to update node.
Now if I run

> nvm list

I get the following

```
v14.17.6
       v18.17.0
        v21.6.0
->       system
default -> v21.6.0
iojs -> N/A (default)
unstable -> N/A (default)
node -> stable (-> v21.6.0) (default)
stable -> 21.6 (-> v21.6.0) (default)
```

Correct me if I m wrong but it looks to me there are 3 node versions in my system and the default one is **v21.6.0**, the latest.
I run

> node -v

but I get

```
v18.12.1
```

which I don' t see in the list. Cool, no problem, let me type

> nvm use 21.6.0

The message is pretty clear: **Now using node v21.6.0 (npm v10.3.0)**

Great, now let's run again

> npm run dev

```
npm WARN cli npm v10.3.0 does not support Node.js v18.12.1. This version of npm supports the following node versions: `^18.17.0 || >=20.5.0`. You can find the latest version at https://nodejs.org/.

> well_github@0.1.0 dev
> next dev

You are using Node.js 18.12.1. For Next.js, Node.js version >= v18.17.0 is required.
```

What am I supposed to do?I tried different things but I always get the same result....
Any idea?

***EDIT***:

Initially I thought there was an interference by these two lines (from FLY.io)

> export FLYCTL_INSTALL="/home/tommaso/.fly" export
> PATH="$FLYCTL_INSTALL/bin:$PATH"

So I deleted fly from the system and got rid of those lines.
ChatGPT told me to insert this line instead:

> export PATH="/home/tommaso/.nvm/versions/node/v21.6.0/bin:/home/tommaso/.volta/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/sn>

Yet when I run echo $PATH the result is preceded by this line:

> /home/tommaso/.volta/bin: (and the rest as above)

Now not only things are not fixed but when I run

> npm run dev

I get the following:

```
npm WARN cli npm v10.3.0 does not support Node.js v18.12.1. This version of npm supports the following node versions: `^18.17.0 || >=20.5.0`. You can find the latest version at https://nodejs.org/.
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path /home/tommaso/package.json
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! enoent Could not read package.json: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/tommaso/package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /home/tommaso/.npm/_logs/2024-01-23T23_22_43_070Z-debug-0.log
```

Comment: It looks like you have a Node.js installation that's **separate** from the ones that `nvm` knows about, and that is earlier in your path than the ones `nvm` knows about. Look at your path (`echo $PATH` or `echo %PATH%`)  and look through it carefully to find the Node.js directory nearest to the beginning of the string. Then remove that installation. Hopefully that will sort it out. If not, try tracking down and removing **all** Node.js installations from your system, then install one fresh.

Comment: Hey @T.J.Crowder thanks for your answer. Unfortunately I have modified the **$PATH** but I still couldn't fix the issue.
I **edited** the question at the end for an update

Answer (score 1):

At the end I made the classic mistake of not reading properly the PATH.
I installed Volta in the past, I don' t even remember when and why, and that caused the whole issue.
Volta apparently "keeps track of which project (if any) you’re working on based on your current directory. The tools in your Volta toolchain automatically detect when you’re in a project that’s using a particular version of the tools, and take care of routing to the right version of the tools for you."

This according to the website, for some reason it didn' t update the required version of node for my project

All I did then was type

> volta install node

to install the latest version of node.
I then ran

> npm install

and had the following error:

> npm install npm WARN tarball tarball data for
> streamsearch@https://registry.npmjs.org/streamsearch/-/streamsearch-1.1.0.tgz
> (sha512-Mcc5wHehp9aXz1ax6bZUyY5afg9u2rv5cqQI3mRrYkGC8rW2hM02jWuwjtL++LS5qinSyhj2QnoNsuc+VsExg==)
> seems to be corrupted. Trying again. npm WARN tarball tarball data for
> streamsearch@https://registry.npmjs.org/streamsearch/-/streamsearch-1.1.0.tgz
> (sha512-Mcc5wHehp9aXz1ax6bZUyY5afg9u2rv5cqQI3mRrYkGC8rW2hM02jWuwjtL++LS5qinSyhj2QnoNsuc+VsExg==)
> seems to be corrupted. Trying again. npm ERR! code EINTEGRITY npm ERR!
> sha512-Mcc5wHehp9aXz1ax6bZUyY5afg9u2rv5cqQI3mRrYkGC8rW2hM02jWuwjtL++LS5qinSyhj2QnoNsuc+VsExg==
> integrity checksum failed when using sha512: wanted
> sha512-Mcc5wHehp9aXz1ax6bZUyY5afg9u2rv5cqQI3mRrYkGC8rW2hM02jWuwjtL++LS5qinSyhj2QnoNsuc+VsExg==
> but got
> sha512-Mcc5wHehp9aXz1ax6bZUyY5afg9u2rv5cqQI3mRrYkGC8rW2hM02jWuwjtL++LS5qinSyhj2QfLyNsuc+VsExg==.
> (5370 bytes)
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
> /home/tommaso/.npm/_logs/2024-01-24T11_41_57_389Z-debug-0.log

that was easily fixed by clearing the cache via:

```
npm cache clean --force
```

Finally I ran again

```
npm install
```

and everything seems working!